# How to explode this into an array of variables?

Tags: php, arrays

I already have the following in place to explode the br's in $tmp..

```
  $tmp = explode('<br>', $tmp);
  echo $tmp[0];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $tmp[1];
```

Now, in $tmp[0] there is a bunch of text, separated by a pipeline "|". ie: word1|word2|word3|word4|word5
take notice, the last once doesn't end in a pipeline..

How can I explode $tmp[0] to grab each bit of text, turn them into an array, ie: $pipetxt[0], $pipetxt[1], etc. without the pipelines..

Can I do the exact same as the above, after the above occurs.. but go;

```
$pipetxt = explode('|', $tmp[0]);
echo $pipetxt[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $pipetxt[1];
```

Thank you!

Comment: So... what's wrong with what you already have again?

Comment: I haven't tested the second explode.. was just checking if that was the correct way and if I was able to do it on an already exploded array?

Comment: Functions *never* care about what something *used* to be, only what it *is*.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "already exploded array". Arrays and strings don't have a concept of being exploded. `$tmp` starts as being a string (some text) and when you explode it you get an array of strings (a "bag" of strings). So your `$tmp` variable now points at a bunch of strings. When you then explode `$tmp[0]` what you are doing is taking the "0th" (first) element of the array (another string) and exploding it to obtain a new array of strings. You can continue in this way indefinitely (the worst that can happen is getting an array with a single string in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explode looks good, and you can output all your `$pipetxt` with [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach($pipetxt as $out)
  echo $out . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

But you should probably adopt some loops.

```
$tmp = explode('<br>', $tmp);

foreach($tmp as $pipeline){
 $pipetxt_array = explode('|', $pipeline);
 foreach ($pipetxt_array as $output){
  echo $output."<br />";
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben - would have chosen this as the answer, although styu was in first with a working method. I'll test yours out shortly, looks great though! Thanks for the advice!